# Switching apps vs 3rd-party launchers on Android 12

Tags: launcher, bugs, android-12

Just bought a new phone with Android 12 and found this app switch failure:

I press "square" button, see recent apps list, tap on one of them. So that app came to top for a moment and then hides away.

I tried Nova, Pixel, Microsoft and Niagara launchers, all with the same effect. The problem don't appear only with stock launcher.

I've found that it can be fixed by disabling "Animator Duration scale" in developer options.

The problem is that I literally can't disable that option - I tap on it, select "Animation off", but value still shows "Animation scale .5x".

Oukitel WP18Pro, Android 12, stock launcher is Quickstep, no root, no custom things. Factory reset also does not help.